# to open a link in whole page rather than inside a frame

Tags: html, css, frame, frameset

I have used frameset and frames to connect 3 html pages.The problem arises when i click on link provided in any of 3 html pages ,those link only opens in their respective frames.so help me so that i can open those link on whole page rather than inside a frame

Answer (score 4):

Use the attribute `target=_parent` in the [`a` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

Answer (score 0):

Where you'd usually use:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">
```

Or to open in a new window:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">
```

Instead, specify the name of your frame as the `target`:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com" target="nav">
```